# How to run a code after a specified time?

Tags: php

I have a big problem:

A user logs in, and the session opens.
After that he clicks a button (in a form) which action is "example.php".
This example.php should increase one record in MySQL database by 1.

How to write this "example.php"?
Please help.

EDIT:
Sorry, I haven't asked what i was supposed to ask.

Main problem:

After a user clicks a button, the example.php script should execute after a specified time, for example, a 600 sec.

The other problem is that the user can click the button and log out, and despite that, the example.php should execute 600 sec later.

EDIT (18:48):
OK, I've read all your suggestions, but dont't have an idea how to make all of this things work together.

I made a form.php, with input type="submit" and action="example.php".
I want to:
 1. start a javascript timer;
 2. increase a value in database after a time, specified earlier in a variable.

Please, if it is possible, give me an example, how to do this.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of your question title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `example.php` execute SQL:

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1;
```

Do you need more info to do that ?

*EDIT:*

I think that there is no other way like jobs mechanism. When user calls `example.php`, you add to the database new job with a current timestamp + 600 seconds.

Parallel there should be running some job executor that will gather from database all jobs that have timestamp set to `timestamp <= NOW()`.

If it will some records, call specified piece of code and remove/mark as done that jobs.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't asked what i was supposed to ask.

Comment: Then edit and clarify your question so I can help you, countryman ;)

Comment: Thanks hsz, thanks to your reply I understood the problem. But even though, I don't have an idea how to write the code :(

Answer (score 0):

You may delay the execution of code using [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Example:

```
<?php
    echo 'Script Start: '.date('h:i:s') . '<br>';
    sleep(5);  // delay in seconds (here 5)
    echo 'Script Ende: '.date('h:i:s') . '<br>';
?>
```

I do not know if what you are trying to do makes perfect sense, but your `exampl.php` would look something like:

```
<?php
    sleep(600);  // delay in seconds
    // the code to be executed delayed here
?>
```

Comment: When you close a site with `sleep` implemented, it will stop executing that script.

Comment: `ignore_user_abort()` and `session_write_close()` (if the OP uses this kind of session) are other functions OP should look into.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could go about doing this...
As mentioned there is the sleep method.
You could have a job - i.e. Add something to a jobs list and have a cronjob check it every so often to see if it is due.
You could use a javascript timer to execute after x number of seconds.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit_button']) ) {

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

    $sql = 'UPDATE table SET counter_column = counter_column + 1'; // WHERE table_name_id =' . intval($id);
    mysql_query($sql, $link);
}
?>
```

This *example.php* will only update the value if the submit_button is clicked on and not if you just type in the URL *example.php*